# Modifying selected email subject

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

In my work I handle over a hundred emails in a day and I always have to add my initials to the front of the subject so others know that I have taken it.

Currently in Outlook 2013 I have to double click the email, mouseclick to the front of the subject, add my initials and /, and then close the email and answer yes to the question "Do you want to change the subject."

I have tried to create a vba button for doing this for me, code is below, but I just can't get it to work. The Error code while running from editor is: Run-time error '424': Object required. while using macrobutton in outlook, absolutely nothing happens. Macro security is set to notify.

So, any help or complete rewriting of the code would be much appreciated!

```
Sub Nimmarit()
Dim aItem As Object

Set aItem = obj.AppApplication.ActiveExplorer.Selection()

Dim strTemp As String
Dim strFilenum As String

strFilenum = "JK/"

If strFilenum = False Then Exit Sub
If strFilenum = "" Then Exit Sub

strTemp = "[" & strFilenum & "] " & aItem.Subject
    aItem.Subject = strTemp
    aItem.Save     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
Sub Nimmarit()
    Dim olItem As MailItem
    Dim sFilenum As String

    sFilenum = "JK/ "

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If

    '// Process each selected Mail Item
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        olItem.Subject = "[" & sFilenum & "] " & olItem.Subject
        olItem.Save
    Next olItem
End Sub
```